# Ещё о "йоте": что такое йотовая палатализация?

Tags: морфология, недопустимая-метка, йотовый-суффикс, йот

> ...Глаголы неоднократного действия зачастую образовывались от глаголов
>   однократного действия, т. е.
>
> съблизити -> съблизиати -> съблизjати -> съближати...
>
> ---
>
> Сблизити - сблизи-а-ти - сблизjати - сближати
>
> "а" - именно тот суффикс, который придаёт несовершенный вид, и -> йот
>   перед гласной переходит регулярно,  [зj] -> [ж'] - как раз та самая
>   йотовая палатализация.

Comment: Вот видео по этому поводу: http://ruskline.ru/news_rl/2013/04/11/jotovaya_palatalizaciya/

Comment: Галина, это вопрос или вопрос с ответом?

Comment: Серж, вопрос, конечно! Я привела пример разговора на тему (с форума), а ответ есть в ролике по Вашей ссылке. Причем оценка и/или характеристика явления - йотовая палатализация - не совпадает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не очень поняла, что нужно объяснить - механизм явления? Вы ж сами всё написали. Йотовая палатализация - это  смягчение согласных в результате воздействия [j]

Теория:

Одно из проявлений тенденции к слоговому сингармонизму в праславянском языке заключалось в том, консонантная группа в пределах слога стремилась к артикуляционной однородности, прежде всего связанной с зоной артикуляции. Другими словами, артикуляторные особенности согласного [j] стали непосредственной причиной изменения сочетаний с ним. Его производство требует значительных мышечных усилий, напряжения органов речи, а поэтому смежные с [j] звуки легко поддаются его влиянию: предшествующий согласный приобретает дополнительную ("йотовую") артикуляцию: средняя спинка языка несколько поднимается, согласный становится палатализованным  или мягким. Действие другого фактора - экономии произносительных усилий  - вызвало обратный процесс: уподобление [j] вновь возникшему палатальному (т.е. артикуляционно сближенному с [j]) согласному.

Задненебные согласные [k], [g], [х], смещая место своего образования вперед, по направлению к среднему небу в позиции перед [j], превратились в мягкие палатализованные согласные. При этом смычные взрывные [k], [g] изменяли способ образования, приобретая фрикативный или смычно-проходной характер.
*kj > k' > ч': *plakjon >  ПЛАЧЪ.
*gj > g' > d'ж' > ж': *lugja > ЛУЖА
*хj > х'j > ш': *duxja > ДОУША.

Палатализация зубных фрикативных согласных [s], [z] также сопровождалась смещением зоны артикуляции по направлению к твердому небу, но уже назад  - развились передненебные фрикативные звуки [ж'], [ш']:
*sj > s'j > ш': *nosja > НОША
*zj > z'j > z': *nozjos > НОЖЬ.

Переднеязычные сонанты [r], [l], [n] в позиции перед [j], не изменяя своей основной артикуляции, становились палатализованными.
*rj, lj, nj > мягкие r', l', n'.
*burja > ,БОУРJA, *volja > ВОЛJA, *konjos > КОНЬ.

Губные согласные  [m], [b], [p], [w] в позиции перед [j] развивали -л- [l]-образный призвук, который затем превратился в согласный полного образования [l]-epenteticum.
pj -> -pl'j- -> pl'pl' -> pl'
bj -> bl'
mj -> ml' *g*emja > ЗЕМЛJА.
wj -> wl'

Судьба сложных звуков типа [pl] в славянских диалектах была разной: возникали рефлексы: [pl] или [p], во всяком случае в позиции на стыке морфем не в начале слова:
Зубные смычные [t], [d] в позиции перед [j] также передвигались по своей зоне артикуляции по направлению к среднему небу.
В результате слияния с [j] возникали долгие палатализованные согласные: *tj [t]; *dj >[d].
tj -> В. ч'
   -> Ю. ш't'
   -> З. t'ш'
dj -> В. ж'
   -> Ю. ж'd'
   -> З. d'ж'

Изменение групп согласных перед [j]. В случае, если перед [j] была группа согласных, она в целом имела тенденцию к палатализации. 
*stj (skj) > s t'ш' > ш't'ш' > ш't'
*zdj (zgj) > zd'ж' > ж'd'ж' > ж'd'/ж'ж'
В восточнославянских диалектах сочетания типа *stj (skj) дали долгие мягкие согласные ш' и ж'; на письме они обозначаются той же буквой, что и "аффрикатоид" ш't' в словах старославянского языка ( лигатурой    , возникшей из сочетания шт). Таким образом, щ в словах русского языка может быть приметой как старославянизма (если соответствующий звук возник из праславянского сочетания *tj или *kt-i; священник, мощь) так и общеславянского слова. Разграничить такие слова помогут наблюдаемые в русском языке чередования: в словах старославянского происхождения щ чередуется с т или к (г) (святой, могу), в общеславянских словах с ст или ск (трещать-треск).

Примеры:
Носить-ношу, возить-вожу, катить-качу, ходить-хожу, рубить-рублю, топить-топлю, томить-томлю (ср. молить-молю, верить-верю).

тишина от тихо - йотовая палатализация (перед и);

рєши от рєк- йотовая палатализация (перед и);

стражь от стерегъ йотовая палатализация (перед ь);

дроужьба от дроугъ- йотовая палатализация (перед ь);

http://cl.rushkolnik.ru/docs/8261/index-10201-15.html

Comment: Как бы я незнающим всё-всё иначе рассказывала б! Палатализация звука - это его НЁБИЗАЦИЯ, а йотовая она не потому, что присутствует звук "й", а по максимальному сходству артикуляции, по сближенности с нёбом, ярче всего выраженном при произнесении  "й"... Правильно ли я излагаю? Что мной неверно понято?

Comment: Кому как понятно, пусть так и говорит, потому и йотовая, что к нёбу идёт, как последующий йот.