# Переход звука с в ш

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это назвать.
Есть слово, например "квас". Еще есть слова "квашня", "кваша", а так же "квасить" и "квашенный". 
Почему звук "с" становится звуком "ш"? Это закон какой то? Наподобие закона Гримма?

Comment: Эта тема обсуждалась на форуме, по ссылке  Вы найдете  нужный материал  (палатализация зубных фрикативных согласных [s], [z]) 
  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419625/Ещё-о-йоте-что-такое-йотовая-палатализация?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Угу, закон.

Он называется ["Чередование предвокальных согласных корня"](https://studfiles.net/preview/3606554/page:20/) и ["Конечные (предаффиксальные) чередования"](https://studfiles.net/preview/3606554/page:20/).

> Центральное место среди конечных чередований согласных занимают **так
>   называемые традиционные, или исторические, чередования, появление
>   которых было вызвано живыми фонетико-­фонологическими законами прошлых
>   эпох развития языка**. Для современного языка такие чередования
>   обусловлены соседством мотивирующей основы с определенными
>   словообразовательными аффиксами (прежде всего — суффиксами).
>
> ...5) Чередования «мягкая шумная зубная — шипящая» или «сочетание
>   щелевой зубной согласной с последующей мягкой смычной зубной —
>   шипящая»; «мягкая губная — сочетание губной согласной с последующей
>   |л’|»: |т’— ч| или |т’—〙’|, |д’— ж| или |д’— ш2д|, |с3т’—〙’|,
>   |с3д’—〇’| или |с3д’— ш2д|, |с’— ш|, |з’— ж|; |п’— п1л’|, |б’—б1л’|,
>   |м’— м1л’|, |в’— в1л’|, |ф’— ф1л’|:
>
> светить—свеч­ение, осветить—освещ­ение; сидеть—саж­ать,
>   наградить—награжд­ать; медведь—медвежий, медвеж­онок;
>   простить—прощение, ездить—прямо­езж­ий, заездить—заезж­ать;
>   нагромоздить—нагроможд­ать; **квасить—кваш­ня, кваш­еный**;
>   возразить—возраж­ать, возраж­ение...

Подробности по гиперссылкам.

---

Так как я не уверена в адекватной конвертации некоторых значков, рекомендую заглянуть сюда:

[АЛЬТЕРНАЦИОННЫЕ РЯДЫ СОГЛАСНЫХ ФОНЕМ](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/alternatsionnyie-ryadyi-soglasnyih-96360.html)

Comment: Благодарю Вас, Галина, за ответ. А это только русское или (и) западнославянское тоже? Или общеславянское? И есть ли работы, которые определяют (или предполагают) "исторические чередования" с каким-то историческим временем?

Comment: Владимир, это уже отдельный вопрос - к этимологии слов; подробнее всего перекличкой с родственными языками занимается Фасмер.